# How to add quadruplets in Tuxguitar?

Tags: rhythm, software, transcription, tuxguitar

I am trying to add quadruplet notes in Tuxguitar, and while the sidebar has a button that adds triplets, quintuplets, etc., it doesn't seem to have the option to add quadruplets.

Is it possible to add them in Tuxguitar?

[image: quadruplets]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quadruplets (and duplets) are not supported in TuxGuitar as of version 1.5. Support for tuplets is limited to sizes 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, and 12. See http://www.tuxguitar.com.ar/. (The screenshot below, showing part of the TuxGuitar feature list, was taken on 29 Oct 2021.)

[image: Screenshot of feature list from TuxGuitar website as of v. 1.5]

Answer (score 4):

While tuxguitar indeed doesn't support such notation, the rhythm (four notes adding up to three sixteen notes) can be notated accurately this way:

[image]